# Fb.UI dont work so fine

Tags: facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui

With the new update of Facebook API, I've been trying show a dialog for share in timeline, but don't only recognize me the `href`..

What can I do?

Code:

```
FB.ui({
        name: 'Mejores Huecas',
        link: 'www.lasmejoreshuecas.com',
        from: '1469541393326876',
        caption: 'Las mejores huecas!',
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://apps.facebook.com/mejoreshuecas/?fb_source=search&ref=ts&fref=ts',
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) {
            //alert('Posting completed.');
        }
        else {
            //alert('Error while posting.');
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That´s intentional, the Share Dialog reads the data from the Open Graph Tags of the URL and it only takes the href as parameter, as you can see in the docs.

If you want to share custom data, you need to create a separate URL with separate Open Graph tags. After all you share a Link, and the message must be user generated anyway, so you don´t really need additional info - i guess that is why Facebook deprecated the old Feed Dialog.